# CircleCI cache bundle install

Tags: caching, rubygems, bundler, travis-ci, circleci

Is there a way to cache my dependencies that I get from bundler (using bundle install)? I know there's the cache_dependencies command that I can use in circle.yml, but I'm not sure what pathway to pass to it.

For reference, in TravisCI, you can cache bundler by using

`cache: bundler`

Comment: This is Kim from CircleCI. Could you create a support request on Circe? We can give you better support there. Thanks!

Comment: kim, could you answer this question once you received a support request and found a solution? Chances are that some other are interested, too.

Comment: @kimh we understand that it's better on your end for this question to be a CircleCI support request, but having that information inside a walled garden does not benefit the greater community who are facing the same problem. In the future, please try and answer questions on SO and duplicate it as a support request if needed.

Answer (score 2):

By default, CircleCI will cache `vendor/bundle` and `~/.bundle` so if you let it run bundler for you everything should be cached automatically.

Comment: Technically this is true. i've found instances where circleci ignores cache data and spends time loading the cache only to run bundle install again, spending a lot more time than if cache was disabled. Not sure if this is specific to my build or not, but I thin it's a CircleCI config issue.

Comment: If you spot that happening, use the in-app help and send us a build URL and we'll be able to track down the root cause.

Comment: I found the following advise from another question:
`bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666176/circleci-gems-caching