# CircleCI gems caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, circleci

Is it possible to cache gems, so that `bundle install` will not install bunch of gems for every build? This takes 5 minutes on every build, that is too much.

I've added this to the `circle.yml` config:

```
dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/"
```

This is the common directory which is provided by `bundle show gem_name` where all system gems are put.

After this addition system writes such log:

```
restoring cache v4/company/repo_name/dependency/circle-ci/42/mGWhlYQIxyOy0GZtt4QmCw__.tar.gz
restoring home/ubuntu/repo_name/vendor/bundle, home/ubuntu/.m2, home/ubuntu/.ivy2, home/ubuntu/.go_workspace, home/ubuntu/.gradle, home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems
```

So, as far as I understand, it restores system gems and gems installed into `vendor/bundle`, however, I still see this (and this takes a lot of time):

```
Installing rake 10.4.2
Installing i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.2
Installing minitest 5.5.1
...
```

instead of

```
using rake 10.4.2
using i18n 0.7.0
using json 1.8.2
using minitest 5.5.1
...
```

So, it seems, it should work, but it does not. What can be wrong?

Comment: I've already found the solution. Will answer later.

Comment: may I ask for the solution you have found? thx.

Comment: I've just added the answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution is simple: CircleCI runs some commands by default and caches gems also by default in `vendor/bundle`, so there is no need to add anything to `cache_directories`.

Among those default commands is `bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3`, that checks presence of gems in the cache directory and installs them if they are not there.

In my case I had project consisting of multiple applications (main application, common UI, API client and API mock) split into 4 different repos. Most of them needed `bundle install` commands.

The only thing I had to do is to replace all my `bundle install` commands (that always installs gems) with `bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3`. In such case all gems are installed only the first time I run tests and all the following builds use previously cached gems.

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  My `circle.yml` file doesn't contain a `bundle install` command, so how to I replace it?

Comment: @PeterH.Boling i'm assuming in that case your circle.yml file is running the inferred commands and you haven't overwritten them.. specify an override and it will use that over the inferred commands.

Comment: Seems to work except for gems with as native extensions

Comment: In case anyone comes across this post, I used this configuration in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44828118/ruby-rails-5-circle-ci-configuration-file/44889844#44889844