# Install a specific set of gems in a CircleCI configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, circleci

I am trying to build a CircleCI configuration file that only installs a specific set of gems via the environment parameter.  In this case let's call that environment `continuous_integration` and this environment matches the `test` environment.  So far I have tried a number of things and this is my current configuration in this spike.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Is this possible?

```
machine:
  timezone:
    America/Los_Angeles
  ruby:
    version:
      2.4.1
  services:
    - redis
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: continous_integration

database:
  override:
    - bundle exec RAILS_ENV=continous_integration rake db:drop
    - bundle exec RAILS_ENV=continous_integration rake db:setup

dependencies:
  pre:
    - gem install bundler
  override:
    - bundle install:
        timeout: 180
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: continous_integration

test:
  override:
    - bundle exec RAILS_ENV=continous_integration rspec
```

Comment: Well, what's the problem at this point? Is it not working at all? Is it only working for some commands? Something else?

Comment: @FelicianoTech I just posted an updated answer, thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS SOLUTION ONLY WORKS WITH CIRCLE 1.0**

From my current research I had to verify the `continous_integration` environment 
was setup correctly throughout Rails inside of secrets, the environments folder, gems, etc.  As it turns out I have discovered that `bundler` does not use the ENV set so I am working with the following configuration know to force cache the gems, speed up the build process, and use the `continous_integration` environment.

**References**

- [CircleCI gems caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666176/circleci-gems-caching)
- https://github.com/sj26/rspec_junit_formatter/issues/50#issuecomment-312787281

**.rspec**

```
--color
--require spec_helper
--format documentation
```

**.circle.yml**

```
machine:
  timezone:
    America/Los_Angeles
  ruby:
    version:
      2.4.1
  services:
    - redis

dependencies:
  pre:
    - gem install bundler
    - gem update bundler
  override:
    - bundle config without development:test
    - bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --without development test --path=vendor/bundle --jobs=4 --retry=3:
        timeout: 180

database:
  override:
    - RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rake db:drop
    - RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rake db:setup

test:
  override:
    - RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rspec --format RspecJunitFormatter -o $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/rspec.xml
  post:
    - gem install brakeman
    - gem install rubocop
    - gem install rubocop-rspec
    - RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rubocop --format fuubar --require rubocop-rspec --config .rubocop.yml
    - RAILS_ENV=continous_integration brakeman -z
```

**Gemfile**

```
group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
  gem 'spring-commands-rubocop'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-clipboard'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  gem 'table_print'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'guard-rake'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
end

group :development, :test, :continous_integration do
  gem 'brakeman', require: false
  gem 'rubocop', require: false
  gem 'rubocop-rspec', require: false
  gem 'timecop'
  gem 'mail_safe'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker', '~> 1.6.6'
end

group :test, :continous_integration do
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'json_spec'
  gem 'json-schema'
  gem 'json_matchers'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'nyan-cat-formatter'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter', '~> 0.3.0.pre6'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'vcr'
end
```

**This setup will yield the correct error output in Circle CI too**

[image]